# defineNuxtPlugin migrating from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, migration, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using a custom plugin to open Modal Window from any component with Component importing.
Now i need to change code to Nuxt 3

Main problem on Nuxt 3 is:

1. params.component get undefined
2. if i createApp - i get another instance, than do not have access to pinia or another plugins :(

Nuxt 2:

**MODAL.TS**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import {DModal} from '@/components/_base-ts/DModal'

Vue.use({
  install(Vue) {
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('d-modal-main-container') as HTMLElement

    let destroyModal

    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$modal', {
      get() {
        return {
          show: params => {
            const instance = new Vue({
              parent: this.$root,
              render: h => h(
                params.component,
                {
                  props: params.props,
                  on: {...params.events}
                }
              )
            })

            const mountPoint = modalContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))

            instance.$mount(mountPoint)

            destroyModal = () => {
              instance.$el.remove()
              instance.$destroy()
            }
          },
          hide: () => {
            if (destroyModal) {
              destroyModal()
            }
          }
        } as DModal
      }
    })
  }
})
```

**modal show:**

```
vm.vnode.context?.$modal.show<string>({
  component: () => import('@/components/address-check/AddressCheckModal.vue'),
})
```

**First try on Nuxt 3:**

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import {DModal} from '~/components/_base-ts/DModal'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use({
    install(Vue) {
      const modalContainer = document.getElementById('d-modal-main-container') as HTMLElement

      let destroyModal

      nuxtApp.provide('modal', {
        show: (params) => {
          const instance = createApp(
                params.component,
                {
                  props: params.props,
                  on: {...params.events}
                }
            )
          
          const mountPoint = modalContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))

          instance.mount(mountPoint)

          destroyModal = () => {
            instance.unmount()
            // instance.$destroy()
          }
        },
        hide: () => {
          if (destroyModal) {
            destroyModal()
          }
        }
      } as DModal)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: got it :) with this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2097#issuecomment-1353942738)